# Need help fetching API data from a object in React not array

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, object, fetch

Good morning I am having a issue with fetching a API in my app I am trying to get to the JSON object information but  I keep getting the this.state.data.map is not a function error, I know that map is supposed to be a array and not a string but I can not seem to fix the code so it pulls in a object rather then a string information the API information I am pulling in from the JSON file is this:

```
{
   "slider":
         {
           "title": "Slider Title",
           "content": "Slider content",
           "image": "Slider.jpg",
           "displaySlideShow": true,
           "displayLearnMoreLink": true
          }
   "content":
         {
           "title": "Content Title",
           "content": "Content Info",
          }
}
```

and this is the code I have written in react

```
class AdminEmailSignups extends Component {
constructor()
    {
     super();
     this.state={ data:[], }
     }

componentDidMount()
     {
          fetch('api/contact').
          then((Response)=>Response.json()).
          then((findresponse)=>
           {
             this.setState({ data:findresponse, })
            })
      }
   render() 
   {
   return (
       <div className="app flex-row adminsections ">
         <Table striped bordered condensed hover responsive>
         {
         this.state.data.map(function(blog){
         return <tbody>
         <tr>
         <td><span>{blog.slider.title}</span></td>
         </tr>
         </tbody>
         })
         }
        </Table>
        </div>
         );
         }
          }
```

I was wondering if someone could review my code and point me in the right direction to help me fix the issue thanks again

Comment: Why do you expect map to work on an object? Take a look at lodash _map: https://dustinpfister.github.io/2018/02/02/lodash_map/

Comment: I do not expect it to work on a object I am looking for the correct syntax that will allow me to pull the json object information in from the API I know map won't work I was looking to see if someone could point me in the correct direction for what does work

Comment: Take a look at the link from my previous comment

Comment: I saw your message thanks for your insight but I was looking for a method that simple pulls the information in using a get request I know I may be overlooking something I was hoping I you reviewed my code you could point me to a answer other then replacing the map

Comment: No time for that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Since map only works for an array, you can create a conditional foreach loop to do deal with this.

Or a quicker way is doing this...

`Object.keys(this.state.data).map(blog => {.... })`

Comment: could you please create a complete example? Im new to reactjs sir. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Update for this.

Assuming you have this in JSON file (containing only 1 key)

```
// sample_data.json
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "posted_by": "posted name",
        "content": "sample content",
        "slug": "adklj-adf32f",
        "title": "title this"
    }
]
```

You can use useEFfect to fetch data.

```
import blogs from '../Model/sample_data.json';

const [getContent, setContent] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
setContent(blogs[0]) 
}, []);
```

Notice the dictionary with an array of [0]. Then you can now display the actual data with this.

```
<div className="display-post__title">
    <h1>{getContent['title']}</h1>
    <span>Posted by: {getContent['posted_by']}</span>
</div>
```

Good luck!